# Java code to find polygonal numbers based on input

Tags: java, eclipse, numbers

I need a program that can do following example:

"What is the number of sides of your polygon?" "3"

"How many of these would you like to see?" "36"

"1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55"

"66 78 91 105 120 136 153 171 190 210"

"496 528 561 595 630 666"

-It has to be able to input the values from the first two questions and print then answers off 10 to a line. I've tried writing the code myself but constantly get stuck in the for loop.Thank you.

This is what I have so far:

```
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  //Request number of sides the polygon must have
  System.out.println("What is the number of sides of your polygon? ");
  n = input.nextInt();

  System.out.println("How many of these would you like to see? ");
  k = input.nextInt();

  long output = polygonalNumber(n,k);
   for (k = 1; k < k; k++);
     if (output % 10 == 0) {
         System.out.println();
     }

 }
     public static long polygonalNumber(long n, long k){

 long p = (k * k) * (n-2) - (k * (n-4))/2;

 return polygonalNumber(n,k);
```

Comment: Please be clear in asking your question and put some code you tried so far so that others can try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks really messed up. But no worries, I wrote a version that supports from 3-6 sides.

Here it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Request number of sides the polygon must have
    System.out.println("What is the number of sides of your polygon? ");
    int sides = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many polygonal numbers do you want?");

    int amount = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    input.close();

    FindPolygonalNumbers(sides, amount);
}

static void FindPolygonalNumbers(int sides, int amount) {
    String numbers = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
        int number = 0;
        if (sides == 3) {
            number = (i * (i + 1)) / 2;
        } else if (sides == 4) {
            number = i * i;
        } else if (sides == 5) {
            number = (3 * i * i - i) / 2;
        } else if (sides == 6) {
            number = i * (2 * i - 1);
        }
        numbers = numbers + number + ", ";

    }
    System.out.println(numbers);
}
```

If you have any questions regarding the code, don't hesitate to ask about it.